# How to load angular application with zone 0.8.5 on click of back button

Tags: angular, webpack, back, zonejs

Im loading my angular application in another (A) application. So there is an option for user to come back to A and again go back to angular application.

With zonejs version 0.9.0 this will work fine, where as it will have an impact in my angular(4) application iframe load(removeeventlistener has got only 1 argument instead of two).

So any idea to reolve this issue with zone js version 0.8.5?

Or by using commonchunkplugins how can i resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved after adding arguments in the ngDestroy removeventlistener. So using zone.js 0.9.0 with the above fix worked for me.